# Solving first-order differential equation $\frac{dN}{dt}=1.2N-0.4N^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the equation
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=1.2N-0.4N^2$$ where $N$ is the population of a species in thousands and $t$ is the time in months. Given that initially $N(0)=1.5$ solve the equation.

The only way I know of solving differential equations is using the separation of variables method, but I can't see how I'd apply that here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can apply separation of variables with partial fractions decomposition. A helpful link on solving these types of equations (logistic growth) is here below:
https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/math214-2-04f/notes/c2-logist.pdf

Comment: How can you fail to apply the separation of variables ?? What did you try ?

Comment: I can't see how to apply the method is the my question

Comment: @H.Linkhorn partial fraction decomposition: $\frac{dN}{1.2N-0.4N^2}=\left(\frac5{6N}-\frac5{6(N-3)}\right)dN$ Can you integrate?

Comment: I edited your title. This equation isn't linear

Answer (score 2):

> *The only way I know of solving differential equations is using the separation of variables method, but i can't see how I'd apply that here.*

**Hint**. One may write the initial differential equation
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=1.2N-0.4N^2$$
 as
$$
\frac{dN}{1.2N-0.4N^2}=dt
$$
$$
\frac{dN}{N\left(1.2-0.4N\right)}=dt
$$ then one may integrate the latter equation with a partial fraction decomposition.